# Add next and prev button to ajax dropdowns WordPress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm using the Ajax Dropdowns plugin for WordPress and I'm trying to get a next and a prev button in addition to the dropdown. So when someone click the Next button the next post should be displayed in the order of the dropdown and the same thing with the prev button.

I added the button like this. On the ajax-dropdowns.php.

```
$select .= '<input type="submit" id="fieldNext" name="next" value="Next">';
```

And now I can go through the posts, but they do not change. I see that I can switch them in the dropdown but the content is not displayed.

I guess the function to get the content is not called at this point. But I don't know which I have to call and how.
Can someone please give me some advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let me know you are using jQuery ajax functionality in wp?

Comment: I just installed this plugin [link]https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-dropdowns/ . There is a chose.jquery.min.js so i guess yes. But there are also some ajax functions in the ajax-dropdowns.php so i'm not sure.

Comment: You need two more option next, prev whenever choose that option regarding to content will change correct!!!

Comment: Tell me exact requirement need option in select box, or next, previous button?

Comment: I already got the select box and now i need 2 extra button. One prev-Button and one-Next button.

Comment: Did you got an idea, how to add these 2 buttons? With the right function?

Comment: Hard code in plugin is possible... we need to customize plugin.